# Вопрос к второстепенному члену предложения

Tags: синтаксис, морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, какой вопрос лучше всего употребить в нижеприведённых примерах к предложно-падежной форме личного местоимения - падежный (за кем?) или обстоятельственный (как? /где?)?

*Подруга шла за мной, разговаривая по телефону.*

*Подруга шла со мной, разговаривая по телефону.*

*Самые гордые самостоятельные женщины...шли за мной, не рассуждая, не спрашивая и делая всё, что я хотел...* (А. П. Чехов "На пути")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы попробовал думать так:

если *шла за мной* значит 'хотела дойти до меня; нсв. к *пришла за мной*', то это – косвенное дополнение («за кем?»);

если *шла за мной* значит 'шла в пространстве за мной', то это — обстоятельство места («где?»).

Comment: То же самое будет наблюдаться и при предлоге "со"?

Comment: Не думаю, что «со мной» может быть употреблено в значении 'в пространстве рядом со мной'. Тут скорее всегда косвенное дополнение, но это чисто интуиция. Предлог _со_ в данном случае указывает на комитативность, на то, что действие выполнялось совместно, но никак не на локацию, пространство. @Alena